# Group running apps in OS X?

Tags: macos, applications, finder, command-line

Since I'm working on several projects that require different resources (shells, files, Chrome windows, etc.), I'd like to organize them better.

Is there a Mac utility or something that will allow me to group a bunch of app windows together to represent a specific task?

For instance I can group Chrome window, Finder window, shell into one group (this would be one project), and then a bunch of those into another group, etc.

Comment: I'm sure there's a third party app that can manage window groups efficiently, I just don't know of any by name.

Comment: I started using spaces, and it works for the most part.  I just have to move apps there manually, and also the dock is obviously shared.  I need something that sandboxes groups of apps tighter.

Comment: I would really like this also. The ability to hide/show groups of windows without having to hide all the other windows. Spaces assumes you want to switch all the active windows rather than working on a subset.
And this is at the window level, not the app level. I might have some chrome windows in project 1 and some chrome windows in project 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An out-of-the-box possibility would be to use Spaces to define applications to go to a specific screen on launch, and navigate between Spaces (Virtual Desktops) as a whole.

Note, however, that you will have a conflict if you want the Finder to be in two places at once :). Your only option is one specific Space, or globally across all Spaces.

Comment: I'm confused by the perceived limitation. I have finders in two spaces...

Comment: It can only automatically open on one Space. You can of course, open a new window *afterwards* and drag it into the new Space. My point was that it will only be automatically on one, or all Spaces.

Comment: right clicking on finder (on dock) -> open new window opens it in the current space.

Comment: Ah, didn't know about that. It generally satisfies my point, "new finder window", but being able to do it when you're already on the new Space is handy. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As @VxJasonxV wrote, Spaces is the solution.

If you want a bigger sandbox, you could probably run a dozen VMs if you had a desktop with 32GB or so of RAM. I think you'll need a license for each VM.